# Javascript inconsitency with Safari/Mac

Tags: javascript, safari

i'm trying to adapt this great script from [Balupton's GitHub](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling) to build a web app. Now everything works fine, but Safari/Mac fails on the first click, which is due to this part:

```
    var first = true;
    $(window).bind('statechange',function(){
      if ( first ) { first = false; return; };
          // stuff
    });
```

I've tested nn  FF and Chrome for Mac and Linux, this works as it should (prevent reloading of the Ajax Part on the first load of the page) but in Safari it prevents the first user activated reload. If I comment out those bits:

```
    //var first = true;
    $(window).bind('statechange',function(){
  //    if ( first ) { first = false; return; };
          // stuff
    });
```

FF and Chrome for Mac and Linux will reload the Ajax bit directly on the first page load. Safari won't.

Can you tell me how to solve this?

Thanks,
thomas

Edit: It turned out to be a problem in `history.js` ...

Comment: If you remove the ; at the end of line 3, what happens? Also, what happens when you correctly close the `.bind(` method? Please pass your code through jslint first. Also, please specify "all other browsers," there's a lot.

Comment: Removing the ; doesn't change anything and the bind() ist correctly closed, I just pasted wrong. I'm guessing Safari just doesn't fire the statechange on first load of the page.

Comment: Oh, and I tested on FF and Chrome for Mac and Linux ...

Comment: `.bind` isn't terminated anywhere in your example. You need `});` not just `}`, the `}` terminates the function, `)` closes the argument of the `.bind` method, and `;` ends the line statement. If you run that code through jslint.com it will tell you this.

Comment: I know. I just pasted the code wrong. The code I'm using has a properly closed bind() and now the one here has as well.